# android libstreaming with MedicaCodec APi buffer size not big enough error

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, libstreaming

I am using libstreaming library and trying to stream with the RtspClient and the MedicaCodec API. I am testing with a galaxy s3 with android 4.4.
  The problem is that no matter if I use buffer to buffer or surface to buffer I get this error : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The decoder input buffer is not big enough (nal=181322, capacity=65536).` and `java.lang.RuntimeException: The decoder did not decode anything.` MediaRecorder api works fine but the quality is so low I can't tell if I have a cat or a dog in front of me.

Here is my code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.Session;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.SessionBuilder;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.audio.AudioQuality;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.rtsp.RtspClient;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video.VideoQuality;
import net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.MediaStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment implements RtspClient.Callback,
        Session.Callback, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    // surfaceview
    private static SurfaceView mSurfaceView;

    // Rtsp session
    private Session mSession;
    private static RtspClient mClient;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surface);

        // Configures the SessionBuilder
        mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
                .setContext(getActivity().getApplicationContext())
                .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
                .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
                .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
                .setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(960, 720, 20, 500000))
                .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
                .setPreviewOrientation(0)
                .setCallback(this)
                .build();

        // Configures the RTSP client
        mClient = new RtspClient();
        String ip, port, path;

        // We parse the URI written in the Editext
        Pattern uri = Pattern.compile("rtsp://(.+):(\\d+)/(.+)");
        Matcher m = uri.matcher(AppConfig.STREAM_URL);
        m.find();
        ip = m.group(1);
        port = m.group(2);
        path = m.group(3);

        mClient.setCredentials(AppConfig.PUBLISHER_USERNAME,
                AppConfig.PUBLISHER_PASSWORD);
        mClient.setServerAddress(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
        mClient.setStreamPath("/" + path);
        mClient.setSession(mSession);
        mClient.setCallback(this);

        // Use this to force streaming with the MediaRecorder API
        mSession.getVideoTrack().setStreamingMethod(MediaStream.MODE_MEDIACODEC_API_2);

        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mClient.release();
        mSession.release();
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRtspUpdate(int message, Exception exception) {
        switch (message) {
            case RtspClient.ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED:
            case RtspClient.ERROR_WRONG_CREDENTIALS:
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                exception.printStackTrace();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionError(int reason, int streamType, Exception e) {
        switch (reason) {
            case Session.ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_CAMERA_HAS_NO_FLASH:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_STORAGE_NOT_READY:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                VideoQuality quality = mSession.getVideoTrack().getVideoQuality();
                System.out.println("APPERROR: The following settings are not supported on this phone: " +
                        quality.toString()+" "+
                        "("+e.getMessage()+")");
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_OTHER:
                break;
        }

        if (e != null) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewStarted() {
        mClient.startStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionConfigured() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStopped() {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSession.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mClient.stopStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitrateUpdate(long bitrate) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted() {
    }
}
```

Please Help! I'm desperate!

Comment: Can you include the full exception? It would be useful to know from where it is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The request for more data came late but I found a solution. As many posts say I had to modify the libstreaming library. I changed:

```
public MediaStream() {
        // code change
        mRequestedMode = MODE_MEDIACODEC_API_2;
        mMode = MODE_MEDIACODEC_API_2;
    }
public synchronized void start() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

        if (mDestination==null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("No destination ip address set for the stream !");

        if (mRtpPort<=0 || mRtcpPort<=0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("No destination ports set for the stream !");

        mPacketizer.setTimeToLive(mTTL);

        // code change
        encodeWithMediaCodec();
}
```

AND had to call to surface method `mSession.getVideoTrack().setStreamingMethod(MediaStream.MODE_MEDIACODEC_API_2);` AND had to limit my config to these values: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations
or it would crash or green screen or whatever.