# Streaming MedicCodec encoder output using libstreaming

Tags: android-mediacodec, wowza, libstreaming

I have successfully compiled the camera streaming example from libstreaming to a Wowza. https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming

I have been googling and still have not found any example on how I can stream my own output from MediaCodec instead.  My scenario is that I am rendering images in OpenGL and then I encode them into a H.264 stream using MedicCodec encoder.  Now, how do I pipe the encoded bytes to libstreaming?

Thanks for reading.  Libstreaming looks so promising for what I need to do.

Huj

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, libstreaming does not fully support MediaCodecs as input yet. If a simple (video only) RTP stream is enough for you, you may just modify the H264Packetizer, RtpSocket and SenderReport classes. The MediaCodec outputs raw NAL units which you only need to feed into the packetizer and send via the RtpSocket.

Comment: Somehow, I am running into other problems.  I compiled the example and I see the connection with the Wowza Engine but no data is transmitted.  Debugging shows that I do have data encoded but on the server nothing. Until I figure this out, I cannot really move on to investigate the MediaCodec issue.

Comment: Which example did you compile?

Comment: I am using Example 3.  I am starting to think that the libstreaming lib is not generating data to be transmitted.  I am still trying to understand the code so it is slow going.  I also noticed the MediaCodec with Surface crashes too so that is another thing to look at.  Thanks.

Comment: I never got libstreaming working with MediaCodec, it seems like you have to modify parts of it to get it working, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267641/android-libstreaming-with-medicacodec-api-buffer-size-not-big-enough-error
As I sad, if you only want to stream video, you don't need more than the 3 mentioned classes.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies.  The sad thing for me is that I was unable to get Example 3 to work right out of the box as well.  Everything seems to be fine and data seems to be transmitted out but I still don't see anything on the Wowza server side.  No errors but just no data.  I did modify the code for MediaCodec Surface encoding and it seems to be working but alas still no data.  Anyhow, thanks for keeping the conversation going while I straddle the on the fence on sanity and insanity.

Comment: Have you tried using Wireshark to verify data is transmitted? There could also be a problem with your Wowza setup, maybe the firewall is blocking the connection. Also, did you check the debug log?

Comment: Sorry didn't see your reply earlier.  I just verified that the Wowza setup is fine using the Wowza GoCoder running on my tablet.  One thing I did notice is that the GoCoder uses a RTMP connection.  Wowza technical support has also looked through the connection logs and everything is good except that there is no data being sent.  must be something on the android side of things but no one else seems to be having trouble using Example 3.   If anything changes, I will definitely update this thread in case others want to know.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check if data is trabsmitted from your phone using wireshark. You don't need Wowza to view the stream from your phone, you can also use VLC or ffplay.

Comment: It is finally working!  After days of looking at this and running out of ideas.  I switched from UDP to TCP and it started to work.  The connection is horribly slow at about 150kbps but at least it is doing something.  Now I can do some real work. Thanks again!